# how to send a variable plus string using expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

```
set user [lindex $argv 0]
expect ">" {send "passwd $user\r"}
sleep 1
```

> trying to send the variable and string 01 to generate a password
> if the user variable is something like Samanta I should send Samanta01

```
expect "UNIX" {send $user"01\r"}
sleep 1
expect "UNIX" {send $user"01\r"}
```

> I have also tried to send as:

```
expect "UNIX" {send "$user"01\r""}
and as
expect "UNIX" {send "$user'01\r'"}
```

Comment: `send ${user}01\r`

Comment: TCL syntax guide: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Expect uses Tcl. try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more comfortable with shell syntax.

Comment: @Heron : Curly braces inhibit expansion of `$...` and `[...]`. You can try it in a tclsh : `set user uu; puts {send "passwd $user\r"}`.